# SharePoint Online - Strategy to Migrate Audio & Video files

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-video-portal

We are in the process of migrating files (from various business units) from File Share to SharePoint Online. For documents (word, pdf etc.,) we are moving them to the document library. Communications department have a Large amount of video and Audio files. (250 GB + and growing...).

What is the best (common sense) approach or options available to store audio/videos in SharePoint Online?

1. SharePoint Document Library
2. SharePoint Assets Library
3. Office 365 Videos portal / MS Stream

Answer (score 1):

My go-to solution would be MS Stream. As far as I know Video is deprecated and will be replaced with Stream.

Stream has a lot of good options for video that SharePoint doesn't have. E.g. depending on your license and language you get automatic transcription.